# Ubuntu doesn't turn off the VM in VMWare player

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player

[image]

Details:

The host OS is Windows 7 home premium x64, the guest OS is either ubuntu x86 or x64 (checked both, the same behaviour).

When I turn off the virtual machine with `halt` - it doesn't turn off after OS finishes its work.

I suppose it is some VMWare behaviour specific to host Windows x64, because I don't experience the same issue on Windows 32bit

Comment: I have no problems to halt ubuntu (VMware Tools installed) with VMware Player 4.0.1 on Win x64 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try `sudo poweroff`. Maybe it makes a difference if you have vmware-tools installed or not.

Comment: Ok, will try it this evening at home

Comment: @zerkms: What exactly was the solution, `sudo poweroff` or vmware-tools?

Comment: It was `sudo poweroff`. Cannot install vmware tools due to some issues with vmware-player 4.0.2 and vmtools (there are a lot of messages in their forum about it, too lazy to read and look for workaround - will just wait until they fix it)